# Facet Chart using Pandas plot.ly

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plotly, pandas-groupby

Currently I am able to aggravate the data successfully by using grouby... etc. But I am not able to create a facet grid. I want individual bar charts for each month which displays the company and count in each chart

I am able to aggravate my data by grouping them by months

Comment: data['Date']= pd.to_datetime(data['Date'],format='%d/%m/%Y')
data['Month']=data['Date'].dt.strftime('%b')
df = data.groupby(['Month', 'Metric']).sum()
months = df.index.levels[0]
for month in months:
    data = df.loc[month]
    data.plot(kind='bar', align='center', title =str(month), legend=True)

Comment: My data format is Count, Date Modified, Company:                     Apple,97,01/01/2019
Samsung,84,01/02/2019
Linux,100,01/03/2019
Microsoft,61,01/01/2019
Blackberry,17,01/02/2019
LG,98,01/03/2019
Panasonic,20,01/01/2019
Apple,100,01/02/2019

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the code from the comments. Do you mean aggregate rather then aggravate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `plotly.express` to create facet charts: https://plot.ly/python/facet-plots/